# Laravel : How to add conditional clause on a model having Many to Many model relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have this method on my `User` Model.

```php
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class, 'review_user')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and its inverse here at `Review` Model.

```php
public function reviewers()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'review_user')->withTimestamps();
}
```

They are connected via a pivot table `review_user` with following structure.

```php
$table->id();
// User ID
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users');

// Review ID
$table->unsignedBigInteger('review_id')->nullable();
$table->foreign('review_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('reviews');

$table->timestamps();
```

The review model has a boolean column `status`.

What I want is a users all reviews which has a status of `true`?

I have been able to achieve `users all reviews` using `Auth::user()->reviews()->get();`

How can I add a where clause, which can filter by status column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) or Defining same Relationship with Extra Where Clause

Using Relation:

```
public function Activereviews()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class, 'review_user')
     ->whereStatus(true)
     ->withTimestamps();
}
```

OR Using Scope:

```
public function scopeActivereviews()
{
    return $this->reviews()
     ->whereStatus(true);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Auth::user()->ActiveReviews()->get();
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code like that, does works

```php
$reviews = auth()->user()->whereHas('reviews', function ($query) {
   return $query->where('status', '=', true);
})->get();
```

And you check [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 0):

like option use [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

> Like all other relationship types, you may call the roles method to continue chaining query constraints onto the relationship:

`$roles = App\User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();`